# Unknown error relating to syntax of tokens

Tags: java, dictionary, syntax-error

I can't work out what is wrong with the following code in Java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class stringCalculator {
    String operator_array[] = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "(", ")"};
    Queue<Integer> outputQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Stack <Object> operatorStack = new Stack<Object>();
    Hashtable<String, String> operatorPrecedence = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    operatorPrecedence.put("+", "2");
```

I am getting the following error:

Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens, This is in relation to the following line:

```
operatorPrecedence.put("+", "2");
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: There's more than one programming language out there - maybe we can tell you more about the syntax error, if you tell us something about the compiler (= language) you use...

Comment: Is this all the error says? _Which_ tokens? This code seems fine. I guess there's a stray bracket or something earlier in the code, and this is just the first place it stops to make sense to the compiler.

Comment: As it stands the code doesn't have a closing brace at the end, but I suspect that is a cut-and-paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You can not put statements directly inside a class.

Create a method or a constructor and put the call to `put` there.

```
public stringCalculator() {
    operatorPrecedence.put("+", "2");
}
```

Also, it is good practice to use an upper-case name for the class, like `StringCalculator`.

Comment: @user3120023 Just wondering: Did this fix your problem, or is there something else?